# rails 3 ajax response from another application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a bug tracking application which is to be used for multiple applications. 
In the application I have a `tickets_controller` thats renders a new form in the facebox using `facebox_render`.

This is working fine when I do this in the same application. 
To make it clear say, bug tracker is running on `localhost:3000` and client application is running on `localhost:3001`

But if I hit `localhost:3000/tickets/new` from `localhost:3001` via an ajax request. It doesn't loads the form at all. I tried putting a `div` in `localhost:3001` app and updating it via `localhost:3000/tickets/new`, doesn't works either.

Is there anything I need to configure or need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the limitations of the XMLHttpRequest and its [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) policy. Simply put, you just can't do cross-site requests via AJAX (which is your case since port number is a part of the definition of the origin).

There are couple of workarounds to this problem that you may want to investigate, eg. JSONP or proxy web service. [This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JSONToJSONP.aspx) sums up couple of possible solutions quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

From the Facebox example, it looks like it loads remote page content via XHR/AJAX. You can only do this with pages on the same domain/port.

In your scenario, you would need to load the page into an iFrame. I don't know if Facebox can do that. Check out [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) as it can do this and is easy to implement.

Comment: Well.. I don't think this is an issue with the facebox. Because as I have mentioned in the question that "I tried putting a div in localhost:3001 app and updating it from localhost:3000/tickets/new, doesnt works either", but still going to try fancybox. Even if it works question remains unanswered on div updating.  Thanks..